# Android layout and drawables folders

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I'm developing an app for API 14 or above.
I have to use folder like this:

```
drawable-ldpi,
drawable-hdpi,
drawable-xxxhdpi,
layout-ldpi,
layout-xxxhdpi
```

OR

```
drawable-sw320dp,
drawable-sw720dp,
layout-sw320dp,
layout-sw720dp.
```

Don't know which have better screen support for cellphones and tablets.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are supporting cellphones and Tablet you need keep both above drawable [http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448451/density-specific-layouts-vs-size-specific-layouts-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to understanding which to use is understanding what they resource qualifiers mean.

The **density qualifiers** (e.g. ldpi, hdpi, xhdpi) specify resources that change based on the density of pixels in the device's screen. This is useful for resources such as images- you typically want your images to be the same physical size on all devices, meaning you need a higher density ("bigger") image on higher density devices.

The **size qualifiers** (e.g. sw720dp, s2320dp) specify resources that change based on the physical size of the device. This is useful if you want to specify that some content on screen should change sizes (or location) based on the screen size. For example, you may want to swap out a list of items on a 4" device for a grid of items on a 7" device.

*Generally* the density qualifiers are used for drawables since you want higher density drawables on higher density devices, and the size qualifiers are used for layouts since you may want to adjust your layouts to better take advantage of different screen sizes.

The two are not, however, mutually exclusive. You can use either qualifier (and many more) with any type of resource to fit your needs. The first step is identifying what you want to do on different devices, then identifying the proper resource qualifiers to achieve your goals.

Comment: My app must show same items in every screen. Onyl change the size of the views depending on the screen. So if i need this you are saying i have to use density qualifiers?

Comment: In general your views will automatically resize to what is appropriate on different screens. It sounds like perhaps you are running into a situation in which this isn't happening, in which case you might want to post a new question with screenshots, some of your layout XML, and a description of what isn't working as expected.

Comment: Im already using the density qualifiers. I want to add the size qualifiers 600 and 720 for layouts. My question is, i have to create a drawable too for this or is going to use some of the density qualifier drawable?

Comment: If you have images that are changing sizes between different layout sizes, then it is completely up to you whether to include variants for the other layouts. If you don't, Android will scale the images for you. If you aren't satisfied with the quality of the scaled images, you will want to provide alternate resources for those configurations.

Comment: Yes but i create a layout for sw720, and the button with an image its too small. I dont know wich drawable density qualifier is getting. I have from hdpi to xxxhdpi.

Comment: The qualifier Android uses to load your layout has nothing to do with the qualifier it uses to load your image. If you have a device with an HDPI screen, then all your resources will come from the HDPI folder. I would start by trying to let Android scale the image by specifying a size in your layout and setting an appropriate `scaleType` on the ImageView, which it sounds like you aren't doing. Using `wrap_content` won't scale your image.

Comment: i think thats my problem. All images have wrap_content. i Saw in the manual that if i want to support multi screen i have to use that. You are saying i have to use a hardcode size? Now im scaling up the images with some calculation

Comment: It depends on your requirements. You also don't need to use wrap_content to support different screen sizes. Sometimes that is the behavior you want, sometimes it isn't.

Comment: The size of all the views in my app must have the same size for every screen. Scale up or scale down. Need to put size with dp?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider multiple [variables](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html): screen size, screen density, orientation.

The easiest way to differentiate cellphones or tablets is to use size qualifiers (check [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vALd3G8NWck)).

But easiest may be not the best, so you have to play with all qualifiers.

A good video with explanation about [resource selection logic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1ZS7uqPy88).

Comment: if i use sw720dp, which folder is going to use in drawable?